# Children's show with "evil" babies

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I remember one episode of a show I saw about 9 years ago, here's everything I remember about it

- I saw it on ABC4KIDS about 9 years ago
- It was 2D animated
- I only saw one episode
- The premise of the episode (and presumably the show) was a group of kids (4-6? And all girls?) Who protect the world from "evil" babies (or toddlers?)

The episode goes something like this:

The children are upstairs when one of the kids mothers comes up saying to go down stairs and say hello to the baby the parents are looking after, as they go down the stairs they wonder what kind of "evil" the baby will be, listing ones such as 'destroys everything they touch' and 'constantly throws tantrums' then they find out that this baby is the worst capable of turning nearby adults into babies, they proceed to follow the adults around protecting them from the baby through various methods, two instances I can remember are: the baby is on a roundabout in a park and turns the parents into babies, one of the girls puts glasses with spiral patterns on them on the baby breaking it's "spell" and the parents immediately take them off saying (paraphrased)

> "why'd you do that!! You could have blinded them!!"

The second time they're at a street corner crossing the road and the baby turns a bunch of adults into babies including a truck driver. eventually the baby returns home at the end of the episode